# How to retrieve a customised list of records according to Repository pattern?

Tags: laravel, repository-pattern

I wanna move the business logic out of controller actions. I read a lot about repository pattern in laravel with tons of examples.

However they're usually pretty straightforward - we have a class that uses some repository to fetch a list of all possible records, the data is returned to the controller and passed to the view.

Now what if our list isn't all the possible records? What if it depends on many things. For example:

- we display the list as "pages" so we might need X records for Y-th page
- we might need to filter the list or even apply multiple filters (status, author, date from - to etc)
- the user can change the sorting of the data (for example by clicking the table column titles)
- we might need some data from other data sources (joined tables) or it might even be used for sorting (so lazy loading won't work)

Should I write a special method with all these cases in mind? Something like that:

```
public function getForDisplay(
    $with = array(), 
    $filters = array(), 
    $count = 20, 
    $page = 0, 
    $orderBy = 'date', 
    $orderDir = 'DESC'
)
{
    //all the code goes here

    return $result;
}
```

And then call it like this from my controller:

```
$orders = $this->orders->getForDisplay(
    array('customer', 'address', 'seller'), 
    Input::get('filters', array()), 
    20, 
    Input::get('page', 0), 
    Input::get('sort', 'date'), 
    Input::get('direction', 'DESC')
);
```

This looks wrong already and we didn't even get to the repositories yet.

What are the best/correct practices for solving situations like this? I'm pretty sure there has to be a way to achieve the desired results without adding all the possible combinations as a method arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use the repository pattern just for business model updates and you'll end up with very specific query methods (the Domain usually doesn't need many queries and they are pretty straightforward). For UI/reporting querying purposes, you can use a simple DAO/Service/ORM/QUery Handler , that will take some input and returns the desired data (at least part of the view model).

Since you're already using an ORM, you can use it directly. Note that you can use the ORM for domain updates also, but inside a repository's implementation i.e the app only sees the repository interface. We care about separation at the business layer, for UI querying you can skip the unneeded abstraction.

Btw, because we're talking about design, everything is subjective and thus, there's no single best/optimum way of doing things.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this too. But the whole point of the pattern is based on several thoughts like tiny controllers, testable "pieces" and "replaceable" repositories as long as they match the contracts (interfaces). If I query the data directly in my controllers or service classes I will depend on eloquent or some query builder I started with. I wonder what's the common practice since everyone has to be running into such cases all the time.

Comment: Common practice doesn't matter, it matters what's optimum for YOUR app. You'll always depend on something, the question is: how easy can you change things? For query purposes, what I've told you is mainainable. If you really want to skip the ORM and work directly with the db, that's ok too. But even if you're using another abstraction, the implementation will change as long as the persistence changes. And you don't need testable and replaceable for querying purposes. There's no business behaviour in querying.